# PuppeteerSharp LaunchAsync failed on Azure as a Windows .net core 5 App service

Tags: azure-web-app-service, puppeteer, chromium, puppeteer-sharp

My service is working perfectly locally however when I deploy it on Azure as a Windows .net core 5 Free App service, It throws following exception. My code is shown below.

What is the reason for this? Do I have to install any additional components?

```
var bf = new BrowserFetcher();
            await bf.DownloadAsync(BrowserFetcher.DefaultChromiumRevision);
            var options = new LaunchOptions
            {
                Headless = true,
                ExecutablePath = bf.GetExecutablePath(BrowserFetcher.DefaultChromiumRevision)
            };

            List<NewsItem> newsItems = new List<NewsItem>();
            using (var browser = await Puppeteer.LaunchAsync(options)) **<= exception thrown here**
            using (var page = await browser.NewPageAsync())
            {
                await page.GoToAsync(url);
Exception: 
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (14001): The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect. Please see the application event log or use the command-line sxstrace.exe tool for more detail.
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
   at PuppeteerSharp.States.ChromiumStartingState.StartCoreAsync(LauncherBase p) in C:\projects\puppeteer-sharp\lib\PuppeteerSharp\States\ChromiumStartingState.cs:line 68
   at PuppeteerSharp.Launcher.LaunchAsync(LaunchOptions options) in C:\projects\puppeteer-sharp\lib\PuppeteerSharp\Launcher.cs:line 63
   at PuppeteerSharp.Launcher.LaunchAsync(LaunchOptions options) in C:\projects\puppeteer-sharp\lib\PuppeteerSharp\Launcher.cs:line 86
   at NewsAnalyzer.AsxNewsManager.GetNewsItems() in C:\Users\t\source\repos\NewsAnalyzer\NewsAnalyzer\NewsManager.cs:line 24
   at NewsApi.Controllers.NewsController.Post() in C:\Users\t\source\repos\NewsAnalyzer\NewsApi\Controllers\NewsController.cs:line 44
   at lambda_method5(Closure , Object )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.AwaitableResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpContextOfT`1.ProcessRequestAsync()
```

Comment: You can refer to [Side by side configuration is incorrect and sxtrace cannot be run](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/2417#issuecomment-366043565)
This is still an open issue at [Chrome headless doesn't work on Azure Functions on Linux](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/4883).